ReferenceError: tinymce is not defined (inside the TinyMCE node_modules file)
In our company product, tinymce is used in certain components. However, when refreshing the page, where those components are used, I get ReferenceError: tinymce is not defined. The product uses some older versions of node, so keep that in mind. The problem seems specific to the node_modules file:
ReferenceError: tinymce is not defined

ReactClassComponent._init

...\node_modules\react-tinymce\lib\components\TinyMCE.js:128
  125 |   }
  126 | };
  127 | 
> 128 | tinymce.init(config);
  129 | 
  130 | (0, _reactDom.findDOMNode)(this).style.hidden = '';
  131 | 

It is in the devDependencies of the package.json:

Here is the index.html file:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="tinymce.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <!-- <script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.2/tinymce.min.js"></script> -->
  <!-- <script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/no-api-key/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script> -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

The node version is 8.17.0
I searched in the web, but there is not a lot of information on the problem. Also it seems that many of the answers are WordPress related.

not saying it's the issue, but is there any reason you're using a version of node that is almost 5 years and 14 major releases old
